# scalability on global data types

Tags: scalability, c1-cms

Does anyone know how scalable the global data types are? I'm trying to make registered user list and wonder if it can support a large number of users (e.g. 100k). The Composite admin UI certainly does not seem to be since it is trying to display all the user data under the tree node. If you have 100k items, I can't imagine it would be.

Anyone has any experience in this area?

Answer (score 1):

The Datalayer doesn't have any problem with this, but its true that you can't use the normal Tree Structure for showing this amount of data. Instead you should create custom pages which shows a paged lists, with search and filtering capabilities.

Here is a guide how to open your own page (aspx, cshtml or something third) from within the console http://docs.composite.net/Console/Guide-to-Applications/How-to-Execute-Custom-Commands